# i am trying to run the drop plot example of coreplot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I am trying to run the drop plot example of coreplot but i am getting the following errors...

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/nagarjun/Documents/CorePlotInstall_0-1.3/Source Code/build/Debug-iphoneos/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CPDecimalFromFloat", referenced from:
      -[CPPlotDocument windowControllerDidLoadNib:] in CPPlotDocument.o
  "_CPDecimalFromDouble", referenced from:
      -[CPPlotDocument windowControllerDidLoadNib:] in CPPlotDocument.o
  "_kCPPlainWhiteTheme", referenced from:
      -[CPPlotDocument windowControllerDidLoadNib:] in CPPlotDocument.o
  ".objc_class_name_CPScatterPlot", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in CPPlotDocument.o
  ".objc_class_name_CPColor", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in CPPlotDocument.o
  ".objc_class_name_CPMutableLineStyle", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in CPPlotDocument.o
  ".objc_class_name_CPPlotRange", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in CPPlotDocument.o
  ".objc_class_name_CPTheme", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in CPPlotDocument.o
  ".objc_class_name_CPXYGraph", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in CPPlotDocument.o
  ".objc_class_name_CPDecimalNumberValueTransformer", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in CPPlotDocument.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I seeing the following linker errors when building an iPhone app with Core Plot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097877/why-am-i-seeing-the-following-linker-errors-when-building-an-iphone-app-with-core)

Comment: See also [Using Core Plot iPhone - Linker error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685363/using-core-plot-iphone-linker-error)

Answer (score 0):

Do you change project settings?

> 1. Copy the CorePlotHeaders directory to your Xcode project
> 2. Copy the Core Plot library to your Xcode project.
> 3. Open your apps Target Build Settings, and for Other Linker Flags
>      include this: 
>      -ObjC -all_load
> 4. Add the QuartzCore framework to the project.
> 5. Change your C/C++ Compiler in the project build settings to LLVM
>      GCC 4.2 or LLVM 1.6.

Comment: Hi beryllium.. i have done all the steps u have given... now it is running without any errors... but its not showing any output..

Comment: Maybe you have some mistakes in sources.. I really don't know the reason why its not showing.